# Error forwarding mail to Public Folder

Tags: exchange-2010

We have some mail-enabled public folders which are members of a distribution list so that they receive mail from external senders. From time to time (not every time) I'm seeing this error for mail that should land in the PF:

```
PSComputerName          : tkgiex10001.mydomain.local
RunspaceId              : a9e561f8-52a6-4ba2-9c16-cef352941d26
Timestamp               : 2/2/2016 10:51:40 AM
ClientIp                :
ClientHostname          : TKGIEX10003
ServerIp                :
ServerHostname          : TKGIEX10008
SourceContext           : 08D32BAF3D3F9D23;2016-02-02T09:51:40.315Z;0
ConnectorId             :
Source                  : STOREDRIVER
EventId                 : FAIL
InternalMessageId       : 12878760
MessageId               : <86e66f2127064f9c9bd1337ff52797ba@EMEA1PEXN02.externalsender.com>
Recipients              : {pf.smax@myexternaldomain.com, TestViews@mydomain.local, MFTest@mydomain.local}
RecipientStatus         : {554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ObjectNotFoundException.MapiExceptionNotFound; Failed t
                          o process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot complete delivery-time pro
                          cessing. 16.55847:EE2E0000, 17.43559:00000000A6020000000000000300000000000000, 255.23226:0000
                          0000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:9E000000, 255.170
                          82:0F010480, 0.18273:00000000, 4.21921:0F010480, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:43000000, 255.1
                          238:6F070000, 4.33375:0F010480, 0.17692:0F010480, 6.5587:0F010480B08440000F010480, 4.33375:0F
                          010480, 0.17692:0F010480, 6.5587:0F010480B08434400F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B002900
                          , 1.36537:0B002900, 6.5587:0F0104800B0029000F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B00060C, 1.36
                          537:0B00060C, 6.5587:0F0104800B00060C0F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:00800800, 1.36537:00
                          800800, 6.5587:0F0104800080080003009580, 4.33375:0F010480, 4.10456:0F010480, 4.5318:0F010480,
                           4.10104:0F010480, 0.57449:0F010480, 4.6025:05000780, 4.5257:05000780, 4.4606:0F010480, 255.1
                          750:00000000, 0.26849:00000000, 255.21817:0F010480 [Stage: Delivery], 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deli
                          ver.Exception:ObjectNotFoundException.MapiExceptionNotFound; Failed to process message due to
                           a permanent exception with message Cannot complete delivery-time processing. 16.55847:EE2E00
                          00, 17.43559:00000000A6020000000000000300000000000000, 255.23226:00000000, 255.27962:0A000000
                          , 255.27962:0E000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:9E000000, 255.17082:0F010480, 0.18273:000
                          00000, 4.21921:0F010480, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:43000000, 255.1238:6F070000, 4.33375:0F
                          010480, 0.17692:0F010480, 6.5587:0F010480B08440000F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 0.17692:0F010480
                          , 6.5587:0F010480B08434400F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B002900, 1.36537:0B002900, 6.55
                          87:0F0104800B0029000F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B00060C, 1.36537:0B00060C, 6.5587:0F0
                          104800B00060C0F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:00800800, 1.36537:00800800, 6.5587:0F0104800
                          080080003009580, 4.33375:0F010480, 4.10456:0F010480, 4.5318:0F010480, 4.10104:0F010480, 0.574
                          49:0F010480, 4.6025:05000780, 4.5257:05000780, 4.4606:0F010480, 255.1750:00000000, 0.26849:00
                          000000, 255.21817:0F010480 [Stage: Delivery], 554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:ObjectNotF
                          oundException.MapiExceptionNotFound; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception w
                          ith message Cannot complete delivery-time processing. 16.55847:EE2E0000, 17.43559:00000000A60
                          20000000000000500000000000000, 255.23226:00000000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 25
                          5.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:9E000000, 255.17082:0F010480, 0.18273:00000000, 4.21921:0F010480,
                           255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:43000000, 255.1238:6F070000, 4.33375:0F010480, 0.17692:0F010480
                          , 6.5587:0F010480B08440000F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 0.17692:0F010480, 6.5587:0F010480B084344
                          00F010480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B002900, 1.36537:0B002900, 6.5587:0F0104800B0029000F010
                          480, 4.33375:0F010480, 1.27420:0B00060C, 1.36537:0B00060C, 6.5587:0F0104800B00060C0F010480, 4
                          .33375:0F010480, 1.27420:00800800, 1.36537:00800800, 6.5587:0F0104800080080003009580, 4.33375
                          :0F010480, 4.10456:0F010480, 4.5318:0F010480, 4.10104:0F010480, 0.57449:0F010480, 4.6025:0500
                          0780, 4.5257:05000780, 4.4606:0F010480, 255.1750:00000000, 0.26849:00000000, 255.21817:0F0104
                          80 [Stage: Delivery]}
TotalBytes              : 39889
RecipientCount          : 3
RelatedRecipientAddress :
Reference               : {<d9d15508-a15d-4de6-a2c2-64b6a0dee960@TKGIEX10003.mydomain.local>, <d9d15508-a15d-4de6-a2c2
                          -64b6a0dee960@TKGIEX10003.mydomain.local>, <d9d15508-a15d-4de6-a2c2-64b6a0dee960@TKGIEX10003
                          .mydomain.local>}
MessageSubject          : acc edf / txs-emed pcoke / 15-24 feb
Sender                  : Nikolai.Jensen@externalsender.com
ReturnPath              : Nikolai.Jensen@externalsender.com
MessageInfo             :
MessageLatency          :
MessageLatencyType      : None
EventData               : {[MailboxDatabaseName, tkgiex10008.mydomain.local]}
```

Anyone seen anything similar before? I'm at a loss here. Considering moving to a new PF database. Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that is usually an issue with the original email message. Something about the formatting or the use of special characters can cause these kinds of problems.

I have seen something similar when server side AV isn't configured correctly and it scans the message and corrupts it. Again usually because of the format of the email or something attached to it (VCARDS and their equivalent I recall having lots of problems when people used to attach those).

A better option is to move away from public folders and switch to a shared mailbox instead - that will also help with a move to a later version of Exchange. The mailbox side is a lot more accommodating to odd formats.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't agree more regarding moving to shared mailboxes. Not my call, unfortunately. We will look at tuning or changing the AV filtering to see what happens.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way of confirming that the problem is message formatting?

Comment: Only by getting the email delivered to a mailbox so you can look at it. You might get something by changing the logs - it isn't something I have done, as soon as I see problems with Public Folders I use it as an excuse to get rid of them.

Comment: haha, I'm with you. Just wondering what to look for regarding malformed messages.

Comment: That is impossible to answer. You can look at the text, look at the headers, the source code if HTML format, simply to see whether there is anything about the email. Not that there is much you can do, other than perhaps configuring things so plain text only is used.